# Loading json into chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I want to load jsonData via ajax into a chart.js object.

My problem is by refering the jsondata as string to chart.js

I think the ajax().responseText retrieves a string but chart.js data expects an array?

I'm doing the same with google chart and it works very well.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./jslib.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./Chart.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
          <h2>Chart Test</h2>
          <div>
            <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
          </div>
        </div>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            var jsonData = $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: { "ibrconfig_id": 26}, 
                url: "./ibrlib.php",
                dataType:"json",
                async: false
                }).responseText;   
            //document.write(jsonData);//   this returns: { labels: ["1","2"], datasets: [ { label: "Taster", data: [0,0], backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.6)" } ] }    
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, 
            {
                type: 'bar',
                data: jsonData
            });

            /*
            This works very fine
            var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
            var myChart = new Chart(ctx, 
            {
                type: 'bar',
                data: { labels: ["1","2"], datasets: [ { label: "Taster", data: [0,0], backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.6)" } ] }
            }); 
            */      
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I handle this? 
Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I got it. thank you andr1o

my jsonData was wrong.

```
{ labels: ["1","2"], datasets: [ { label: "Taster", data: [0,0], backgroundColor: "rgba(153,255,51,0.6)" } ] }
```

no i changed it to

```
 { "labels": ["1","2"], "datasets": [ { "label": "Taster", "data": [0,0], "backgroundColor": "rgba(153,255,51,0.6)" } ] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse(jsonData)` to make an Object from json string

Comment: doesn't work ... 
var objData = JSON.parse(jsonData);
type: 'bar',
data: objData

Comment: can you show contents of `objData`? you can use `console.log(objData)` for that, you'll output in web inspector